# View sorting issue related to Content Translation

Tags: views, transliteration

I have used **Content Translation** module to translate nodes in zh-hant.

They are extracted at the View block using **Content: Translation language (= Interface text language selected for page)** filter and sorted by **Content: Weight (asc)**, which is a bunch of integers.

The nodes are placed in a correct order in en(the original language) but not in zh-hant. In my case, they are placed with weight order 3, 1, 2.

Is it a bug of the module or I have done something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Weight translatable at **[Configuration > Regional and language]** can solve the problem although it makes no sense at all.